# Pandas: find pairs of duplicate rows for one column with additional condition based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with 2 columns (TrackTRUEPt, EventNumber) and approximately 500k entries. I want to keep pairs of data points with the same TrackTRUEPt value, but also in addition having a difference in EventNumber of ±1 i.e. consecutive EventNumbers. I cannot simply use the 'duplicated' method, as in my dataframe there are typically more than two data points with the same TrackTRUEPt value, so duplicated retains all of them, rather than just the pairs I want.

```
    TrackTRUEPt      EventNumber
0   15049.719727         1
1   15049.719727         2
2   5530.503906          3
3   3943.318115          4
4   1760.578979          10
5   1760.578979          11
6   15049.719727         12
7   4931.394043          21
8   4931.394043          22
9   3943.318115          23
10  11068.919922         24
```

For this particular case you would only retain the pairs (row 0, row 1), (row 4, row 5) and (row 7, row 8) as all of these pairs have the same TrackTRUEPt value and in addition have consecutive event numbers i.e.

```
EventNumber(row 1) - EventNumber(row 0) = 2 - 1 = +1, 
EventNumber(row 5) - EventNumber(row 4) = 11 - 10 = +1, 
EventNumber(row 8) - EventNumber(row 7) = 22 - 21 = +1
```

The expected output dataframe would be

```
        TrackTRUEPt        EventNumber
    0   15049.719727          1
    1   15049.719727          2
    4   1760.578979           10
    5   1760.578979           11
    7   4931.394043           21
    8   4931.394043           22
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to do this.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: So the two rows have to be next to each other?

Comment: @SurajSubramanian The expected output would be a dataframe containing only the consecutive pairs. I don't want to drop duplicates, rather I want to keep duplicates with consecutive event numbers

Comment: @JosephChotard Yes that's right, when they're sorted by EventNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For count consecutive values create helper `Series` by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and get counts by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with compare only `2` for consecutive pairs by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
g = df['TrackTRUEPt'].ne(df['TrackTRUEPt'].shift()).cumsum()
df1 = df[g.groupby(g).transform('size').eq(2)].copy()
print (df1)
    TrackTRUEPt  EventNumber
0  15049.719727            1
1  15049.719727            2
4   1760.578979           10
5   1760.578979           11
7   4931.394043           21
8   4931.394043           22
```

And then is possible subtract last value with first by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df2 = (df1.groupby('TrackTRUEPt')['EventNumber']
          .agg(lambda x: x.iat[-1] - x.iat[0])
          .reset_index(name='diff'))

print (df2)
    TrackTRUEPt  diff
0   1760.578979     1
1   4931.394043     1
2  15049.719727     1
```

Or because pairs is possible use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
a = df1.drop_duplicates('TrackTRUEPt').set_index('TrackTRUEPt')
b = df1.drop_duplicates('TrackTRUEPt', keep='last').set_index('TrackTRUEPt')

df2 = b['EventNumber'].sub(a['EventNumber']).reset_index(name='diff')
print (df2)
    TrackTRUEPt  diff
0  15049.719727     1
1   1760.578979     1
2   4931.394043     1
```

Comment: Hi, so I think that the first part of your answer is exactly what I am looking for, as I do not want to drop duplicates, rather I want to keep all pairs of duplicates with consecutive EventNumber and drop all non-duplicates or duplicates that are not paired by EventNumber! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pronitron - Can you add expected output DataFrame to question?

Comment: Done. It is the output DataFrame in your first code snippet.

Comment: @Pronitron - Supe, glad can help ;)